# How to declare/attach a ViewModel for a UserControl in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm developing an application (c#, wpf) using MVVM Light library.
I have a main window with ViewModel attached as `DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`. That's OK.
But in the main window I have Different UserControls. Which one is used at the moment is defined by a switcher like:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Type1}">
      <controls:UC1 Content="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The question is how to declare ViewModel for the UserControl and to link it to the UC `DataContext`. And it would be very good if this will support design-time demo data.

Comment: Why would you want to "declare ViewModel for the UserControl and to link it to the UC DataContext"?  This is done automatically when you are using DataTemplates and ContentControls correctly.  This suggests that either 1) you're not, or 2) you're creating view models specifically to control how your user control behaves.  I can't tell from your question if #1 is true, and if #2 is true, stop that.  Does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel?  No.  MVVM != no codebehind. UI logic goes in your codebehind.

Comment: @ Will Yes I link my UC DataContext now. And you are right my main aim is  to control UC behavior (#2). Why I want to do it is because that UC is rather complicated (in fact each control is a small program, but I want to integrate several under the main window).

Comment: Creating ViewModels that control the behavior of your UserControls can cause you mischief.  Most often by interfering with the flow of the DataContext.  You may find yourself trying to bind pseudo-DataContext-like properties to your view models, or having problems juggling what is in the DataContext.  The solution is to not do this.  Put your UI logic in the codebehind.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Type1}">
  <controls:UC/>
</DataTemplate>
```

and also add

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ViewModelObj}">
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: "The question is how to declare ViewModel for the UserControl and to link it to the UC"

Comment: <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ViewModelObj}">
  </ContentPresenter>

Comment: @A.S.Mahadik : If you have more information to clarify your answer, you should edit your answer to include the new information; that way, any reader can understand your entire answer without having to also read the comment history.